# Visual Studio is skipping to every other line while debugging

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010

I try to step through my code now, Visual Studio skips every other line.

(I know it is every other because when I have a ForEach loop it will hit the lines that it skipped on later iterations.)

Is there any logical reason for Visual Studio to skip every other line?

**UPDATE:** I have added a youtube video of this happening [here](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CIWelNpWUcE&feature=youtu.be).  This only happens in this one solution.  I have tried rebuilding, cleaning then rebuilding... I am at a loss for what to do.

**UPDATE:** Several comments have asked for a code sample.  I am posting one, but I really don't think the code is the issue.  I have many thousands of lines of code and it is skipping lines anywhere I put a breakpoint.

Here is a code sample just incase it could somehow matter:

```
foreach (string commentText in comment.CommentLines)
{
    // Set the base path for this segment
    basePath = rootPath + XPathsForComment.OrderRoot.Expression + "[@Id='" + index + "']/";
    // Sequence
    XPathToXML.Set(document, basePath + XPathsForComment.Sequence.Expression, commentIndex.ToString());    
    // Comment Type
    XPathToXML.Set(document, basePath + XPathsForComment.TypeCode.Expression, CommentCodes.CommentCode);    
    // Comment
    XPathToXML.Set(document, basePath + XPathsForComment.TextAttribute.Expression, commentText);
    // Empty xmlns
    XPathToXML.Set(document, basePath + XPathsForComment.XmlnsAttribute.Expression, "");
    commentIndex++;
    index++;
}
```

Things I have tried:

- Rebooting
- Deleting the Folder that holds the source and getting it from Source Control again.
- Switching from Debug to Release and back to Debug (doing cleans an Rebuilds each time)
- Clean and Rebuild in Debug.

Comment: By any chance are you running a release build in the debugger?

Comment: @ChrisO - good idea to check, but no, I am running Debug mode.

Comment: Have you tried restarting Visual Studio?

Comment: Similar question:  http://stackoverflow.com/q/1505823/33690

Comment: @Xaisoft - I tried restarting Visual Studio and Cleaning and Rebuilding in both Debug and Release.  It is also happening in all files now.

Comment: What type of project? ASP.NET, WPF, Winforms?

Comment: Probably loaded symbols are out of date. Try to clean up the solution, then rebuild it and debug. And if it doesn't work, could you please provide us the small piece of code where you can watch this behavior?

Comment: @ChrisF - It is happening in one solution (that has 40 projects in it).  Most of the projects are Class Libraries.  But some are WCF and "Entity Framework" (EF is really just a Class Library project with EF stuff in it).

Comment: @Kate - I added a YouTube video of the line skipping for you to see.  I have tried a clean an rebuild and it does not help.

Comment: @Vaccano Unfortunately I don't have access to the youtube now. Could you provide this piece of code right here?

Comment: @Kate - I added a code sample to my question.

Comment: Are you sure it is loading and running the new build?  Depending on paths, the startup application, etc. it could be running an older release build.  Something like Process Explorer might help verify that it is indeed loading the latest assemblies/DLLs/executable (whatever is being built).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Turns out it was a Extension that was the culprit.  I had installed the beta of a tool called Bug Aid.

Seems that this problem started right around when my Trial License ran out.

I don't know if it is direct cause an effect.  But when I uninstalled Bug Aid, my debugging was no longer skipping lines.

Comment: Thank you for the report and sorry again for inconvenience it caused! The issue was fixed in the latest version of BugAid.