# Visual Studio 2010 debugger points to wrong line

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, debugging, cuda, nsight

The debugger in Visual Studio 2010 is recently pointing at the wrong lines and/or skipping lines and I have no idea why this is. This is a CUDA project and only happens in CUDA files. I've noticed the following:

- It always happens at the same part of the program.
- The lines it points to are always the same, i.e. not random.
- Putting extra code *after* the culprit lines changes which lines it points to.
- It only happens in `.cu`-files. Moving the code to a `.cpp`-file does not recreate the problem.

What I have tried:

- Clean and rebuilt the solution.
- Install SP1 for MSVC10 and do all possible updates via Windows Updates
- Set the compiler to *not* use optimizations in debug mode for both `C/C++` and `CUDA C/C++`
- Manually delete all created files and then rebuild from the solution folder.
- Deleting the folder `C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files`
- Recreating the solution only using the source files.
- Disabling my extensions.

I've managed to reduce the code to the following which might reproduce the problem. Mind that this code has to be inside a .cu-file and most probably needs to be compiled with the cuda compiler for C/C++. Including boost is not really necessary, but this example does show what problems I'm having. A shorter example is at the back.

```
#include <boost/numeric/ublas/matrix.hpp>
using boost::numeric::ublas::matrix;

struct foo {
    foo() : mat(NULL) {}
    matrix<float>* mat;
};

bool func(foo *data) {
    bool status; // <- skipped line

    status = false;
    if (status) {
        std::cout << "test\n";
        return (status); // <- error reported here
    }

    int size = data->mat->size1(); // instead of here

    return status;
}

int main(int args, char* argv[]) {
    func(NULL); // force error by passing NULL pointer

    return 0;
}
```

Does anyone have any idea how to solve this or how this could be happening? It's pretty annoying having to debug this way.

---

Shorter example only showing the skipping lines. No external libraries necessary.

```
bool func() {
    bool status; // <- skipped line
    status = false;
    return status;
}

int main(int args, char* argv[]) {
    func();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Related questions: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3144880/visual-studio-2010-debugger-skipping , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4934073/visual-studio-2010-debugger-jumps-around , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1505823/visual-studio-2008-crazy-debugger-skipping , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8917717/visual-studio-is-skipping-to-every-other-line-while-debugging

Answer (score 2):

Since the program only contains CPU instructions and variable declarations of types that have no construction contain no instructions, the debugger will not stop there. It just executes instructions and then uses the debugging information that the compiler provided to find the relevant line of source code.

Comment: That only explains why it skips lines, but not why this only happens in .cu-files and why it points to the wrong line. In a .cpp-file the line with `bool status;` is not skipped. Also mind that optimizations are explicitly turned off.